# Why does mathematica keep using my CPU?

Tags: evaluation, memory

After I finish running an evaluation Mathematica still keeps using up CPU and can sometimes take up high amounts of RAM. This is a problem for me as I use a laptop and it easily over heats.

The funny thing is that this behaviour *always* occurs after an evaluation has finished and can continue on for hours. It only stops once I exit the kernel.

Comment: I suggest contacting the tech. support. But for the record, which version do you use and on what OS?

Comment: I experience exactly the same behavior. For unknown reason (and not always), Mathematica keeps one of my CPU's busy and only killing the session helps. To this day, I was not able to reproduce this consistently or fix it. Although I think the question cannot be answered and doesn't fit here, I'm going to upvote it. Are you able to create a minimal example that keeps the CPU busy after finishing?

Comment: Personally I have never seen this, but I do see a *small* constant CPU usage by all kernels (~1%). For a question like this it is essential to mention at least: Which process uses the CPU (kernel or front end)? What precise version of Mathematica? What operating system?